# Restore sphere to orientation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, transform, interpolation

Though I begin with a very nicely, oriented globe:

[image: Good]

After a lot of manual intervention and spinning, the globe may look like this:

[image: Bad]

Obviously, I should be implementing some sort of restoration function that will restore the globe on a certain axis to a point.

I have naively created the following code:

```
if(transform.parent.rotation.eulerAngles.y != 0)
{
     goalRotation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.parent.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.parent.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0); 
     transform.parent.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.parent.rotation, goalRotation, Time.deltaTime);
}
```

However, this obviously does not work.  It is definitely rotating the globe, but it's not moving as expected...

Is there anyone with more experience with Slerp or something similar that can rotate my globe to a 0 point?

As always, any help or advice is much appreciated.

EDIT: In case I wasn't clear before, I am looking to achieve something like this: https://gfycat.com/PeacefulJubilantCottontail  (This is my solution to the problem).  I did try to use other solutions here, but I guess there was a misunderstanding because they did not work.

While, the following naive code sorta works, I still feel there is a better way to do it...

```
if (fix && (lastControlled + 5f < Time.time))
{
    goalRotation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(90, transform.parent.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    transform.parent.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.parent.rotation, goalRotation, Time.deltaTime);
}
if (fix && (transform.parent.rotation.eulerAngles.x == 90) && (transform.parent.rotation.eulerAngles.z == 0))
{
    fix = false;
}
```

The only real remaining issue I am having is that Slerp works towards the desired point, but it does not take the quickest path.  Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to restore the globe rotation the the angle it was before you rotated it? If this is true, do you want to restore immediately  or restore it within time, slowly?

Comment: Obviously, I could write my own code to do it after a period of time.  I can handle that aspect, but I'm not sure of how to restore it just along a single axis.  So like if I do a crazy amount of stuff to it and let it go, the equator will go back to being horizontal.

Comment: Just store a original rotation and return that.

Comment: Did not answer any of my questions. Do what @Gunnar B. suggest. Good luck.

Comment: also Quaternion.Identity is a quaternion representing no rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
quaternion defaultRotation = transform.parent.rotation;
bool returnToDefault = false;

void Update()
{
    if(returnToDefault)
    {
        Vector 3 rot = new Vector 3 (transform.parent.rotation.x, Quaternion.Slerp(transform.parent.rotation, defaultRotation, Time.deltaTime).Euler.y, transorm.parent.rotation.y);
        transform.parent.EulerAngles = rot;
    }
}
```

And just change the variable returnToDefault to true whenever you want it to go back. Otherwise, you are constantly fighting your code, which as your wrote it is always rotating it back to default.

Comment: I'm only looking to restore a single axis though.  The rest of the orientation should be preserved.  Imagine, if I rotated it so I can look at the bottom.  When I let go, my script could set returnToDefault (as you suggest) and it will move back toward the center.  I don't want it always looking at one spot, but rather have it restore some initial up back to up.  Does that make sense?

Comment: See my edit. Although, that is fairly unoptimized code, but it should at least get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: See my edit.  Your code did not work.  Any chance you can have a look at my code / video?

Comment: Oh I see, that is odd, it shouldn't do that. I've only ever had it take the shortest way back (which would be kinda diagonal motion). I'll see what I can find. Probably throw a quick test together in unity to see if I can reproduce it.